# tfsaggregator dont copying field to child

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

I am using new tfs aggregator from https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/

Numeric fields are working great. 
But now i have a request to copy text field from from parent to child.

i wrote that rule

```
<rule name="FieldCopy"
      appliesTo="*">
<![CDATA[
    if (self.HasChildren())
    {
      foreach (var child in self.Children)
        {
            child["Title"] = self["Title"];
        }
    }
    ]]>

</rule>
```

But it dous not work. Where can i find any examples with child aggregations? Or what have i done wrong?

UPD: It works good with text fields like Title. But Fields with type FieldControl dont copying.

Answer (score 2):

I got it!
All child or parent WITs must have changing field. If one of all will not have it  changes will not be saved.

Comment: Correct, you can check whether a child has a certain field or wrap the assignment in a try/catch block. I'd recommend the first, as it's faster.